# Devise - Require password in some cases, only email in others

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm working on an application where I'd like to introduce "Progressive Engagement" in certain cases. I've been using [this guide](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Email-only-sign-up), which is helpful, but doesn't do exactly what I'm thinking: I'd like the ability to require a password when signing up with some forms, but only an email when signing up with other forms.

Anyone have advice on how best to go about doing this? Thanks!

Comment: It isn't pretty, but http://railscasts.com/episodes/235 and http://railscasts.com/episodes/236 give a decent explanation on how to change Devise to work with an omniauth provider. This isn't 100% what you are looking for, but sometimes you require a password, and another time you don't. May come in handy.